# How to "float" an absolutely positioned element div out of its container

Tags: css

Here's the (simplified) scenario. I have a div which contains another div.  The outer div is of fixed size, has scrollbars and relative positioning. The inner div is larger than and is positioned relative to the outer div. I want the inner div to be fully visible, "floating" above the outer div.

I appreciate this sounds artificial as there is no point in constraining the size of the outer div in this way. It is. In the real application though, there is other content inside the outer div which does need to be controlled with scrollbars.

How can I do this, using css alone? Please note, the inner div must be positioned relative to the external one, so using position:fixed is not an option.

Markup:

```
  <div id="container">
    <div id="popup">Popup Text</div>
  </div>
```

Css:

```
#container{ 
  overflow: scroll;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:relative;
}
#popup {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

Here's a [Plunker](http://embed.plnkr.co/BiNnBgQiguQmN46Rotjj/preview)

Comment: Is there a reason this element must be a child and cannot be a sibling?

Comment: Since you have overflow hidden in the parent, no.

Comment: @Patsy: Doesn't work if overflow is hidden: http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/Yjpmu/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add extra wrapper and set `position: relative` and `overflow` to different wrappers:
HTML

```
  <div id="base">
      <div id="container">
        <div id="popup">Popup Text</div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

CSS

```
#base {
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  position:relative;
}
#container{ 
  overflow: scroll;
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
}
#popup {
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  border:1px solid #000;
  height:100px;
  width:100px;
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/UGftq/

The "secret" is that [the `overflow` property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#overflow)

> ...affects the clipping of all of the element's content except any
>   descendant elements (and their respective content and descendants)
>   whose containing block *is the viewport or an ancestor of the element*.

The [containing block](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#containing-block-details) for absolutely positioned elements is the nearest ascestor with non-static `position`. Therefore, when element with `overflow` is not positioned itself, it doesn't clip absolutely positioned descendants.

Comment: Wow, that's esoteric, but it works! Good explanation. Only problem is that I can't control the fact that the containing block is inside the viewport (I hope I use those terms correctly). The actual application uses a grid component whose correct presentation depends on various predefined styles. Is there any other way of tackling this?

Comment: @PaulTaylor, if the markup is under your control and you can add this extra wrapper and move `position: relative` to it, then the predefined styles shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: parts of the markup are under my control, but unfortunately, I can't change the fact that there is a relatively positioned ancestor of the element I am interested in between it and the element that has `overflow:scroll` set.

Comment: For this situation, unfortunately, I don't know the solution(

Comment: Ilya, given the scenario that I initially outlined, this is certainly the answer. Thanks!